# UIView subViews not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am sure this is a very stupid issue. I am trying to add UIImageView as subview to UIView. The code that I am trying for adding subview is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kBoardSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < kBoardSize; j++) {

        Tile *t = [[Tile alloc] initWithPosition:CGPointMake(i, j) withSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];

        [self insertSubview:t atIndex:0];
        //[self addSubview:t];
        //[self bringSubviewToFront:t];

        [temp addObject:t];
    }
}
```

The corresponding Tile(which is a `UIImageView` subclass) code is:

```
- (id) initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position withSize:(CGSize)size
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(position.x * size.width, position.y * size.width, size.width, size.height)];
    self.tag = position.x * kBoardSize + position.y;
    [self setPiece:EMPTY];
    if (self) {
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now when I do

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[self subViews] description]);

2012-05-22 23:20:51.740 XXXXXXX[8204:f803] (
    "<Tile: 0x6a79380; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a7ad70>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a94180; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 106.667; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a93e40>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a97da0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 213.333; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a97de0>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a7aeb0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (106.667 0; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a7aef0>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a94610; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (106.667 106.667; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a94650>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a946c0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (106.667 213.333; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a94700>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a94770; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (213.333 0; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 6; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a947b0>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a94820; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (213.333 106.667; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 7; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a94860>>",
    "<Tile: 0x6a948d0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (213.333 213.333; 106.667 106.667); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a94910>>"
)
```

It shows that the subviews are added properly. But the subviews dont actually show up in the view. What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you add the view itself to the hierarchy?

Comment: The main UIView? Yes. I added it via IB.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. After adding it via IB, I was re-initializing it in the `viewDidLoad` of my view controller. And then I was calling the init function of my UIView. After I removed the re-initialization code `self.gameView = [[TicTacToeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];` it is now working fine!

Stil confused though that why re-initialization is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vashishtha Jogi, you should take a look on [The Designated initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html), and how does it work. Main point is that any of initSomething method calls designated initializer eventually, so it is important to call it properly.